# How many times should one implement the same datasource protocol method for UIPickerView

Tags: ios, uipickerview

If I have 2 pickers in the same viewcontroller, how many times should I implement this method:

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only implement a given method once in a single class. If you want to support two pickers with a single controller, just have the delegate methods look at the `thePickerView` parameter, which tells you which picker is asking for data.

Comment: Hi, i didn't really understood your answer, typically, i have two pickers and i need to specify for the first array1 and for the second array2, how can i do ?? thx

Comment: should i test the name of the picker (if else) ??

Comment: The picker delegate is usually the same object that created the picker, so it's not unlikely that your controller might have ivars that point to each of the pickers. You can compare `thePickerView` to each of those ivars. Alternately, set the `tag` property for each picker to a different value when you create it, and then check the `tag` property of `thePickerView` in your delegate methods.

Comment: what is the "tag" property ??

Comment: It's an integer. Each view has one, and you can set it to whatever you like to to help you identify views. Please see the reference page for UIView.